# How to get Attribute and its related values from dynamically generated fields in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have attribute and its related attribute values dynamically generated on my view, user can fill and that attribute with values can be saved in table.

```
<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_1]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_name[attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Name" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">

<input type="text" name="attribute_value[][attr_2]" placeholder="Attribute Value" class="form-control" required="">
```

I'm passing here the random key to the attribute name and that same name is passed to attribute values array as a key so that when i get the data through post i can distinguish and relate attribute with there respective attribute values and save it in same row.

> One thing to note is the fields are created dynamically and it is not
> created using loop, but it can be added by clicking on Add button.

now i' getting data using something like this :

```
 foreach($request->attribute_name as $attribute)
                 {
                    
                 }
```

but this i cannot get the attribute and its related values.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input

You can access those fields by doing

```
$request->input('attribute_name.attr_1')
```

Using dot notation for each array level down

Comment: but if i don't know the key, how will i retrieve that, because in my case first i have to get the attribute key then its related attribute values with that key.

Comment: You can do $request->input('attribute_name.attr_.*')

Comment: I tried this print_r($request->input('attribute_name.attr_.*')); but i'm not getting any values, i'm getting other values like $request->category

Comment: I want to loop through all the  attribute name and access the key and then access its values using those key in that same loop

Comment: Consider resrtucturing your fields into a more friendly format? You can always do something like `name="attribute[][value]"` and `name="attribute[][name]"` then you can refer to them like  `$request->input('attribute.*.value')` and `$request->input('attribute.*.name');` You can also `dump($request->input());` to see how the data is coming back